# Large graph traversal : which library should be used?

Tags: sql, graph, neo4j, social-networking

I have to deal with graph traversals in BFS fashion, upto 3 degrees away. The problem is in the size of the graph, I have almost a million nodes and a few billion edges in total. The times taken by my naive implementation of SQL is far too slow, is there something specific that I could implement? Or is it better if I switch to a graph database like Neo4j? Does anyone have benchmarks of such scale?

Comment: This is the use case of a graph database.

Comment: I agree with @WesFreeman. In my own use case transition from SQL to neo4j resulted in a really tremendous performance boost. It's not that SQL is bad, it's just not made for such a kind of tasks. For example, you almost surely have a lot of recursive sub-queries in your SQL code, and I, again, almost surely guarantee that it's a bottleneck. When you switch to neo4j, it will become possible for you to write a *really* simple traversal procedure to get what you want with much less effort.

Comment: I just want to know how effective it is, switching to a graph DB. A lot of the people who I've asked tell me that SQL is still comparable to a graphDB, I just have a hard time buying that. How much effort, and cost-effective is porting the entire backend to a graph DB, in the use case I've illustrated, and which looks likely to scale as time progresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question really depends upon the 'Connectivity' of your database. You can traverse ~1 million edges a second. So if your 3 degree hop needs to traverse most of your data it will be very slow, however if it needs to traverse only a few nodes it will be quick.

Think of it like sitting in a football stadium. If your 3 hops are 'who' is sitting within 3 seats of you, you don't have many nodes to traverse.
However if your query is 'which Liverpool supporters, have a scarf and are dressed in red?', it will take a long time.

Also neo4j at the moment has a 32 bit address space for its nodes and edges, so you might run out of space with your billions of nodes.

Hope this helps

Comment: Did you mean in SQL or in a graphDB? Because I can't seem to replicate a million edges per second in SQL. As for the connectivity, I'll be traversing O(n) vertices in each query, so it will be connecting to most of my data, or at least, it'll have many duplicates within the nodes to be visited.

Comment: a million edges in neo4j